# A cache with timer paradox akin to a race condition

Tags: caching, architecture, race-condition

I'm pulling updates from a link and saving them to cache (database). Each update has a timestamp. We'll use human-readable times to exemplify the issue.

These updates are an array of timestamps: `[16:30, 16:34]`. Every time I create a view with these updates, I look at the last item, in my case `16:34` and compare it to a value I've stored **which represents when that view was accessed, the "last viewed time"**, the reason for why I need it is so that, on the next request (users can refresh their page), I can tell the user if there are new notifications or not:

```
//Start with the assumption that there are no new notifications.
new_notifications_count = 0;

for( notification as notification ) {
    if( notification->time > last_accessed_view_tiem ) {
        new_notifications_count++;
    }
}

return new_notifications_count;
```

This will run on every request on that page, so the check is being done every time the user accesses the page, but the system will only ever store when the user last clicked on the view, well, if he clicks.

Now, here's where things get messy: I check for new updates every 60 minutes and then store them in the database as to not make a HTTP request on every page access.

Let's assume the last time I stored the notifications in the database was at `16:37`, meaning that the next refresh of data is at `17:37` but I pushed an update at `16:55` and accessed the view at `17:05`: even when the next update comes in, the latest update's time will be `16:55` and it will be compared to `17:05`, the system (above code) will say "oh, no new notifications, actually." even if there clearly are.

Here's a visual of all this:

[image: bogaloo]

How can I solve this race condition?

Comment: Just as I published this, it hit me: `store the timer of the last seen notification instead of the time when someone clicked the view`. Maybe it'll help someone brighter to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

As I've guessed in my comment, to overcome this issue, you just simply have to start with a `last_seen_time` of `0`, then, every time the user accessed that view, make the `last_seen_time` the time (when the update was published to the public JSON) **of the last update that the user received instead of when he clicked the view.**

This way, even if an update is published to the public JSON before the user clicks the view again, it'll still be seen by the user as new on a new refresh.

In other words, instead of passing `Date.now()` from the front-end when the user clicked the view, simply go through all notifications and pick the timestamp of the latest one `jQuery('.all-updates').first().find('.update-time').attr('data-timestamp')` to be used as `last_seen_time`.